# ¿Por qué la consulta devuelve 7 filas pero la variable devuelve un count de 1?

Tags: php, sql

¿Por qué si la consulta en sql(phpMyAdmin) devuelve 7 filas, la variable $numero_filas2 saca un echo de 1?

```
$consultaContar="SELECT count(*) FROM preguntas";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con,$consultaContar);
$numero_filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
echo $numero_filas;
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, dónde estás asignando el valor a la variable
    $numero_filas2 ?

Comment: El "2" sobra perdona. Sigue la pregunta en pie.

Comment: No se que intentes pero la funccion count(*) solo cuenta las filas 1 resultado y mysql nums rows cuentas las filas resultantes osea solo 1, asi tengas 4 millones de filas en tu tabla

Comment: si @Bryro cuenta solo una fila, pero esa única fila contiene un valor; que es el que se desea recuperar, que si lo haces desde la consola de mysql obtienes una fila pero te da un valor por ejemplo 7

Comment: Contestando a tu pregunta. y puede que me equivoque es porque solo le estas pidiendo el numero de filas en concreto osea solo 1 fila [fuente](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Debes darle un $res = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado); echo $res[0];

Answer (score 0):

declara tu Consulta colocándole a la función de agregación un alias, que será el que recuperaremos después

```
$consultaContar = $con->query("SELECT count(*) AS Total FROM preguntas");
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior, pasamos la variable que contiene la consulta, al método `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

```
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaContar);
```

Por último como solo estamos obteniendo un resultado que es el que genera la función de agregación, de este modo

```
var_dump($resultado["Total"]);
```

Si te fijas al momento de mandar a imprimir a la variable `$resultado` al mismo tiempo le indico que acceda al valor que pusimos como alias mas arriba llamada `Total`

Que al final te debe devolver 7

Ahora para respetar la estructura de código que manejas en tu pregunta, te dejo como debería de ir

```
$consultaContar = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) AS Total FROM preguntas");
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaContar);
var_dump($resultado["Total"]);
```